# How can I get subdomain users that are members of group in main domain

Tags: java, recursion, active-directory, jndi, active-directory-group

My goal is recursive getting all group members from domain and subdomains using only connection to main dc.
I have Active Directory forest containing `domain.com`, `sub.domain.com`.
My '`MainGroup`' located in `domain.com` and contains members/groups from `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com.`

I'm getting `'member'` field strings of `MainGroup` using `ldapContext` connection with `dc.domain.com`. Here is it:

```
cn=userA,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
cn=userB,ou=Users,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com
cn=groupB,ou=Users,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com
```

Can I get subdomain's user/group data (I need `ObjectClass` to recursive iterate) using current `ldapConext`?

---

```
private LdapContext createLdapContext() {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user@" + domain);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "******");
    try {
        ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ldapContext;
}

public List getGroupMembers(String groupName) {
    List resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int Start = 0;
    int Finish = 1499;
    int Step = 1500;
    boolean Finished = false;
    String Range;

    try {
        while (!Finished) {
            Range = Start + "-" + Finish;
            String[] returningAttrs = {"member;range=" + Range};
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=" + groupName + "))";
            SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
            searchControls.setReturningAttributes(returningAttrs);
            searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            NamingEnumeration answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();

                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                if (attrs != null) {
                    for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                        Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                        if (attr.getID().endsWith("*")) {
                            Finished = true;
                        }
                        for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                            resultList.add(e.next().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Start = Start + Step;
            Finish = Finish + Step;
        }
        ldapContext.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

**Edited. Found another solution:**

1. Anyway we should query every domain.
2. We can make  'recursive one shoot query' using filter `(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=Group1,OU=groupsOU,DC=x)`

[Related c# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602297/how-can-i-query-if-a-user-of-one-domain-is-a-member-of-a-group-in-another-ad-dom?rq=1)

[msdn Search Filter Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx)